# How to efficiently copy strided data from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, rgba

Imagine an array of RGBA data as obtained from a [`canvas.context.getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) call.  Is there a way to extract e.g. the second channel out of it in a more efficient way than walking through it?

```
var source = canvas.context.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);
for(var i=0; i != data.length; ++i){
  target[i] = source[i*4 + channelOffset];
}
```

Comment: Since it is a 1D array of concatenated RGBA arrays, there is no other way than walking through it. I think you could use Array.reduce though, but technically it is also a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient your code is, and I can almost guarantee that you won't get much more efficient by looping through the imageData. What I would suggest is using the canvas globalCompositeOperation to extract the channel to another canvas, I have a running example on this pen:

http://codepen.io/Aeyos/pen/egyEQQ

And also here:

```js
var canvas1 = document.querySelector('#canvas1');
var canvas2 = document.querySelector('#canvas2');
var canvas3 = document.querySelector('#canvas3');

var img1 = document.querySelector('#img1');

var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');

ctx1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
ctx1.fillStyle = "#F00";
ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 435, 318);

ctx2.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
ctx2.fillStyle = "#0F0";
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 435, 318);

ctx3.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
ctx3.fillStyle = "#00F";
ctx3.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
ctx3.fillRect(0, 0, 435, 318);

//http://wallpaper-gallery.net/single/image/image-13.html
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-13.jpg" /><canvas width="435" height="318" id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas width="435" height="318"  id="canvas2"></canvas>
<canvas width="435" height="318"  id="canvas3"></canvas>
```

You can also change the globalCompositeOperation to any of these:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation

Each channel takes around 200ms to complete the operation, good news that it's probably the same time for large images.